# Is there possibility to assign 0 for another occurence of the same user?

Tags: sql

I have table like this:

[image]

And lets say I want to have in another occurence of login eg. 1234 i would like to have instead of 275 value of 0, the same for 3678 instead of 300 i would like to have 0. I want to have profit/loss only for first occurence in the table. Is this somehow possible to do it in SQL?

Comment: Yes, but you have to define which login of the two is "the" first.

Comment: It can be first occurence in the table of specific login

Comment: Use CTE and Row_Number() to order the occurrences of each Login over some ID field which I presume you have though it is not shown. then use case statement where say rowNumber <> 1 replace with zero. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: There is [no such thing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/186885/5203) as "first occurrence" in a database.

Comment: @Lukasz . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to keep the highest / lowest, you can join the table with itself.

If you only want the first (as in lowest row number) occurance you can use a window function and update all occurances > 1

```
UPDATE SUB
    set profit = 0
FROM (
    SELECT
        profit,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Login ORDER BY Login) as cnt
    FROM table
) SUB
WHERE SUB.cnt > 1
```

Comment: Exactly i did like that just before your response and it is working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In Standard SQL, you can use:

```
update t
    set profit = 0
    where profit > (select max(profit) from t t2 where t2.login = t.login);
```

Note that specific databases may have alternative ways to writing this.  However, your question does not have a database tag.

Also, this assumes that your table does not have duplicates.  Unfortunately, duplicates would be problematic if these are the only two columns in the table.